# Why does $('html').offset().top return a static value in IE8 but variable in normal browsers?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

Specifically, I am talking about this code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ var loc = $('html').offset().top; });
```

To give some context, it's a long scrolling page with nav in a fixed position. I'm using this to track user mouse-based scrolling and update the navigation. It works a treat in Firefox & Chrome - the value of **loc** changing when I scroll the mousewheel - but in IE it remains at -2.

Not sure if this is relevant, but I'm coding the page using html5 so my doctype is the basic:

```
<!doctype html>
```

And I'm using latest jquery library.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: do you have `html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}` in the CSS  - if not, does adding it help?

Comment: yes, I do have that in the CSS. Thanks though, as I hadn't considered that the problem could lie with the CSS. I'm assuming it's to do with the javascript, and specifically IE8's handling of the html DOM element. But my js knowledge isn't mega deep so I could be way off there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by using:

```
var loc = $(window).scrollTop();
```

Works in IE8 now. Yet to test in IE 7 & 6. As I suspected problem lay with my poor javascript knowledge. Hope this helps someone.